# How to enable alternative StyleCop rules (prefixed with SX) when using StyleCopAnalyzers (Roslyn)?

Tags: c#, .net, stylecop, static-code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

For an existing C# web project I am trying to setup StyleCop code analysis based on Roslyn analyzers. (DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers)

I have managed to get it to work quite fine for our desired code-style except that we would like to not use these default rules:

- SA1101: Prefix local calls with this
- SA1309: Field names must not begin with underscore

Instead we want to somehow enable these alternative rules mentioned at stylecop.pdelvo.com as *DisabledAlternative*

- SX1101: Do not prefix local calls with 'this.'
- SX1309: Field names must begin with underscore
- SX1309S: Static field names must begin with underscore

The mentioned site shows that these alternative rules even have code fixes implemented so I expect them to be available for usage.

I have searched the net repeatedly and only found proposal posts to introduce these rules and other documentation on how the rules work, how to suppress them etc., but not how to enable them.

Using **GlobalSuppressions.cs** file I can only suppress some rules but I am unable to enable any.

Documentation on using **stylecop.json** to fine-tune some rules does not mention that either.

How do I enable these alternative rules?

Adjusting the existing code to pass the default rules is not an option and simply disabling the SA1101 and SA1309 rules works but is not optimal either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty same way as other rules.

1. Right Click on Project > Properties > Code Analysis
2. You should see Rule set which is currently used in your project. Click open
3. You should see list of rules grouped by rule family like 'StyleCop analyzer rules', 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features' etc. Your desired rules are under 'StyleCop analyzer rules'

You can speed up search by typing SX into filter field

[image: Filtered rules]

Check your rules, try to build project and you should see warnings/errors where **this.** is used

Comment: Awesome! Obviously I was never there. The defaults worked out-of-box so I did not even know there are such configuration options. Thank you for a swift resolution!

Comment: What about the ruleset file syntax itself?