# Configure StyleCop Analyzers (Roslyn) in Rider

Tags: roslyn, jetbrains-ide, rider, stylecop

I am not able to configure the StyleCop Analyzers (Roslyn) in Rider.

I saw this answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44440682/12505827) already, but I cannot find `Code Analysis` in my project properties.

I also tried Inspections and checked every menu item, but I cannot find a single thing, which would allow me to change the settings to enable/disable some rules.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you're referring to is a) pretty old and b) only valid for Visual Studio.

Within Rider, you have two options:

1. Use StyleCop Analyzers (probably your most preferred option, as you've tagged your question with `roslyn`) ([see here](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/DotNetCli.md) and [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/StyleCop_Styles.html#using-stylecop-analyzers)) → for this you've to install the analyzer `StyleCop.Analyzers`
2. Let Rider import settings from StyleCop settings files ([see here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/StyleCop_Styles.html#applying-settings-from-settings-stylecop-files))